# WebDav - documents are opens in readonly mode

Tags: webdav

For testing purpose, I am trying to implement the edit and save document from webpage by using WebDav dotnet API.

But i am unable to save the Microsoft office documents to server from client due to documents opens in read only mode.

Could you please help  me to solve this problem

oNs.JavaEditDocument(webDavServer + sDocumentUrl, webDavServer, javaApletFilePath);

Answer (score 1):

Typically if the document opens in read-only mode, it has to do with settings on the server side. Check with your server admin to make sure that you have permission to edit and save.

If you find that your permissions are correct and you are still having problems, test with a WebDAV client such as WebDrive. If you can edit through the client you can at least validate that the server has the permissions set correctly.